Error while adding subscriber in SQL Server replication process
I get this error while adding subscriber database in SQL Server:

Property Password cannot be changed or read after a connection string has been set. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Some resources asked to change the connection string for subscriber server, but the path they've mentioned is not available in my SSMS.
What should I do to fix this problem and add the mentioned server as subscriber server?
